# UML Diagrams for JavaScripts using Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, spring-tool-suite

I have a couple of JavaScripts and I want to derive their UML diagrams from the JavaScript code.

I am using Eclipse Spring Tool Suite.

Can anyone tell me how can this be done? I tried using JS/UML plugin but was unable to do so.

I need the steps to follow to derive the UML diagram (especially sequence Diagram) directly from JavaScript code in Eclipse.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download X-ray eclipse plugin in zipped format here: http://xray.inf.usi.ch/xray.php

Unzip to your eclipse plugins folder.

Then right click the project you want to analyze and click "analyze with xray"